# Vue CLI adding inline css background image, path is wrong

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

Like as many others, i can't seem to get the right path..

using @/assets/drive.jpg

Ive tried: ~@/assets/drive.jpg, ~/assets/drive.jpg, @/assets/drive.jpg

When I hardcode it in my css, it works, but as soon I try to put it inline (for dynamic purposses) it wont allow me.

```
<div>
      class="hero-image"
      :style="{
          backgroundImage: `url('${imageUrl}')`,
          backgroundPosition: `${imagePosition}`
      }"
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a reason why that doesn't work.

`@` is an alias that webpack interprets. It will do that for imported files and the `<style>` blocks, but when you have it as a string in template, it will not handle it. It may also not move the images from assets into dist folder.

Unfortunately, you will most likely need to find another way to do this. If you can expand on your desired outcome, you may find a suggestion that fits best.

For example, you could have them images already in your dist/assets, and then use relative path in style like: `/assets/drive.jpg`.

If you know the list of images you'll be using, you can add them using `require('./assets/drive.jpg')` in the component, or even inline. But because this work is done at compile time, you won't be able to use `require(imageUrl)`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, Daniel! It works when i put it in my public folder. I just read that it was bad practice to do so. Ill try and look for other ways, i was just afraid it was a stupid syntax error.

Comment: You can use `require` to inject the assets from `src` to `dist`